# How to clean up deeply nested dictionary access?

Tags: python, refactoring, nested

Here's a snippet from inside a python class used in a web scraping project. I want to iterate through a dictionary of freshly scraped data, comparing it to the previously scraped index at each level, and adding values that need updating to another deeply nested dict for later processing. What strategies can I use to clean this up and still accomplish the same results?

```
self.new_stats[tour] = {}
parsed_stats = parse_stat_year(CURRENT_STAT_YEAR, self.scraped_stats_index[tour])

for pname, stats_by_year in parsed_stats.items():
  if pname in self.raw_players_with_stats[tour]:
    player = self.raw_players_with_stats[tour][pname]

    if 'stats' in player:
      for y, stats_by_cat in stats_by_year.items():
        if str(y) in player['stats']:
          for cat, stat in stats_by_cat.items():
            if cat in player['stats'][str(y)]:
              for prop, val in stat.items():
                if (not prop in player['stats'][str(y)][cat]) or (player['stats'][str(y)][cat][prop] != val):
                  self.new_stats[tour].setdefault(pname,{}).setdefault(y,{}).setdefault(cat,{})[prop] = val
            else:
              self.new_stats[tour].setdefault(pname,{}).setdefault(y,{})[cat] = stat
        else:
          self.new_stats[tour].setdefault(pname,{})[y] = stats_by_cat
    else:
      self.new_stats[tour][pname] = stats_by_year

  elif pname in self.new_player_urls[tour]:
    self.new_stats[tour][pname] = stats_by_year
```

Comment: Better suited for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Changing the format of the dictionary to a more flat structured is acceptable for you? An other option could be to split that code into some independent passages using(e.g.) generators and then combine the generators together. This will still do the nested loops but it ought to be more readable if done properly, since the generators would "abstract" the intermediate steps,  and allows you to better maintain the single conceptual passage of that code.

Comment: Quite frankly - if it works - leave it be. I'd put it in a function, with an appropriate docstring and err, just leave it. Short of some dark-magicky stuff - more effort that it's worth - let the dogs keep sleeping!

Comment: Why shouldn't this be on SO? It's a python specific question about how to clean up a specific block of code. If this was ruby, clojure, or even javascript, I would have no trouble writing this in a more readable style, but I have less experience with python, so I'm not sure how to go about it. It's not a general programming question.

Comment: @Bakuriu Interesting. If you have time, could you possibly show how generators could be used in such a situation? I'm not very familiar with them.

Comment: First, I would build a unit test to be sure that when I mess with the code, the result is still valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with [unit test](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) to ensure that after each refactoring iteration my code still actually works.

I would use meaningful data structures and methods, so the code is more [self-describing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting). Sometimes you can find [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) very useful for that if you don't want to roll out a separate data-holder class.

Finally I would decompose this big and ugly `if...for...else` block into meaningful smaller chunks, something like this:

```
# instead of this original code...

for pname, stats_by_year in parsed_stats.items():
  if pname in self.raw_players_with_stats[tour]:
    #...
  elif pname in self.new_player_urls[tour]:
    self.new_stats[tour][pname] = stats_by_year

# you get something like this

for player_name, stats_by_year in parser_stats.iteritems():
  if self.has_raw_player(player_name):
    self.process_new_raw_player(player_name, stats_by_year)
  elif self.is_player_new(player_name):
     self.insert_new_stat_for_player( player_name, stats_by_year )
```

which is easier to read, test and understand

And, if you have some free time, I would invest it in reading [Clean Code by Robert Martin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882). It will pay off surely!

**Edit**

Clean up lengthy and difficult to read one-liners like this

```
#...
self.new_stats[tour].setdefault(pname,{}).setdefault(y,{}).setdefault(cat,{})[prop] = val
#...
```

So it looks, for example, like this:

```
def insert_new_stat(self, tour, pname, y, cat, prop, val):
  player_stat = self.new_stats[tour].setdefault(pname, {})
  y_param = player_stat.setdefault(y, {}) # what is y??
  category_stats = ...
  prop_stats = ...
  ... = val
```

Your code certainly will be more lengthy and verbose, although [Explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: Thanks. Unit tests and breaking this up into smaller, better described methods definitely sounds like a good place to start. But what about some of the inner assignments like:

'self.new_stats[tour].setdefault(pname,{}).setdefault(y,{})[cat] = stat'--

Will I still need code like this in my new methods, or is there a better way to accomplish such tasks in python? Or would I be better served to avoid deeply nested dicts entirely in a situation like this one?

Comment: @Dane: use back ticks ``, not ticks ' ', to mark code inline